# Find closest point in Cartesian coordinates to another point with movement constraints?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been practicing algorithms and I have found one that took me weeks and still couldn't solve. I couldn't come up with a complete algorithm but I have been working on an idea, and the code I wrote so far is :

> **Note:** The reason I shared comprehensive problem is not to enlong question rather that I might have misunderstood the main point of problem at first place.

**PROBLEM**

A PropBot can only make two distinct movements. It can either **move 10 cm** forward, or turn towards the right by **45 degrees**. Each of these individual movements takes **one second of time**.

**Input**

Your module has two inputs: the Cartesian coordinates of a point on the plane that the PropBot wants to get as close to as possible, and the maximum number of seconds that can be used to do this. At the beginning of the navigation, the robot is located at the origin, pointed in the +x direction. The number of seconds will be an integer between 0 and 24, inclusive. Both the x and y coordinates of the desired destination point will be a real number between -100 and 100, inclusive. The first entry in the input file will be the number of test
cases, t (0 < t ≤ 100). Following this line will be t lines, with each line containing three entries separated by spaces. The first entry will be the number of seconds PropBot has to get close to the point. The second entry is the x-coordinate of the point, and the third entry is the y coordinate of the point.

**Output**

Your program must return the distance between the goal point and the closest point the robot can get to within the given time. Your result should include at least one digit to the left of the decimal point, and exactly six digits to the right of the decimal point. To eliminate the chance of round off error affecting the results, we have constructed the test data so the seventh digit to the right of the decimal point of the true result is never a 4 or a 5.

Sample Input

2

24 5.0 5.0

9 7.0 17.0

Sample Output

`0.502525` <- HOW ?

`0.100505` OK

**JAVA CODE**

**Enum Direction**

```
public enum Direction {

EAST(1), N_EAST(2), NORTH(3), N_WEST(4), WEST(5), S_WEST(6), SOUTH(7), S_EAST(8);

private int direction;
private int index;

Direction(){
    direction = 1;
    index = 0;
}

Direction(int dir){
    direction = dir;
}

int getDirection(){
    return direction;
}

public int incrementDir(){
    if(direction > 1 && direction <= 8){
        direction = 8 - index++;
        // Rotate towards right side

    }
    else if(direction == 1){
        direction = 8;
        index = 1;
    }
    return direction;
}
}
```

**Abstract - Calculation.java**

```
import java.awt.Point;

public abstract class Calculation {

public static Direction getDir(Point p){
    int line = getCloseLine(p);
    switch (line) {
        case 1:
            return Direction.EAST;
        case 2:
            return Direction.N_EAST;

            // 2nd Quadrant
        case 3:
            return Direction.NORTH;
        case 4:
            return Direction.N_WEST;

            // 3rd Quadrant
        case 5:
            return Direction.WEST;
        case 6:
            return Direction.S_WEST;

            // 4th Quadrant
        case 7:
            return Direction.SOUTH;
        case 8:
            return Direction.S_EAST;

    default:
        return Direction.EAST;
    }
}

public static int getSelectedLine(Point p){ 
    int a = getCloseLine(p);
    return a;
}

public static int getQuadrant(Point target) {
    double x = target.getX();
    double y = target.getY();
    if (x > 0 && y > 0)
        return 1;
    else if (x < 0 && y > 0)
        return 2;
    else if (x < 0 && y < 0)
        return 3;
    else if (x > 0 && y < 0)
        return 4;
    // Means point lies on an Axis not in any Quadrant
    return -1;
}

public static int getAxis(Point target) {
    double x = target.getX();
    double y = target.getY();
    if (x > 0 && y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (x == 0 && y > 0)
        return 2;
    else if (x < 0 && y == 0)
        return 3;
    else if (x == 0 && y < 0)
        return 4;
    else if( x == 0 && y == 0)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}

public static double getAngle(Point v2) {
    double d = v2.getY() / v2.getX();
    double ang = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(d));
    return ang;
}

public static int getSector(Point point) {
    double angle = getAngle(point);
    int quad = getQuadrant(point);

    if(quad == -1)
        return -1;          

    switch (quad) {
        case 1:
            if (angle < 45.0)
                return 1;
            else
                return 2;

        case 2:
            if (angle < -45.0)
                return 3;
            else
                return 4;
        case 3:
            if (angle < 45.0)
                return 5;
            else
                return 6;
        case 4:
            if (angle < -45.0)
                return 7;
            else
                return 8;
    }

    return -1;
}

public static int getCloseLine(Point p) {
    int sec = getSector(p);
    double angle = getAngle(p);
    System.out.println("ANGLE : " + angle);

    if(sec == -1){
        int axis = getAxis(p);
        switch(axis){
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            return 3;
        case 3:
            return 5;
        case 4:
            return 7;
        case 0:
            return 0;
        }
    }

    switch (sec) {

    case 1:
        if (angle < 22.5)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    case 2:
        if (angle < 67.5)
            return 2;
        else
            return 3;

        // 2nd Quadrant
    case 3:
        if (angle < -67.5)
            return 3;
        else
            return 4;
    case 4:
        if (angle < -22.5)
            return 4;
        else
            return 5;

        // 3rd Quadrant
    case 5:
        if (angle < 22.5)
            return 5;
        else
            return 6;
    case 6:
        if (angle < 67.5)
            return 6;
        else
            return 7;

        // 4th Quadrant
    case 7:
        if (angle < -67.5)
            return 7;
        else
            return 8;
    case 8:
        if (angle < -22.5)
            return 8;
        else
            return 1;

    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner s =  new Scanner(System.in);

    int time = 0;

    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    System.out.println("Enter time: ");
    time = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println( " X: ");
    p.x = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println( " Y: " );
    p.y = s.nextInt();

    if(!(time > 0 && time <= 24)){
        s.close();
        System.err.println("INPUT ERROR!");
        return;
    }
    // Initialize bot facing +x direction
    Bot b = new Bot(p, Direction.EAST);

    int line = Calculation.getCloseLine(p);

    while(time != 0 && b.getDirectionInt() != line){
        // Rotate the face towards the point
        b.rotate();
        time--;
    }

    s.close();
}

}
```

**Bot.java**

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Bot {

private Point location;
private Direction direction;

public Bot(){
    location = new Point(0, 0);
    direction = Direction.EAST;
}

public Bot(Point loc, Direction dir){
    location = loc;
    direction = dir;
}

public Point move(){

    return location;
}

public int rotate(){
    direction.incrementDir();
    return direction.getDirection();
}

public int getDirectionInt(){
    return direction.getDirection();
}
}
```

My approach was to divide the Cartesian plane into sectors and get a closet line to the input point and rotate the bot and then move ahead.

**First issue :** I got how the second case output was evaluated but I don't have any idea about the first one.

[image: Graph of the points]

Line distribution as follows :

[image: Line distribution]

**Second issue :** If the bot moves diagonally (45 degrees) and then move either horizontally or vertically, after that it seems as if the whole Cartesian plane has moved and the code I wrote is not valid anymore.

Is my approach correct? if yes then how I improve it further?
If my approach is wrong? Please suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Do we assume that PropBot starts at (0,0)? Do we assume that the coordinates are in cm? That is, does (5,5) correspond to 5 cm to the right of the origin, and 5 cm above?

Comment: @JimMischel Starts at (0,0) indeed with Bot facing +x direction. Again yes for the unit in cm because when you try to evaluate the given input with the above assumptions you get the given output result. That proves that it's in cm.

Comment: Did you try backtracking? 2^24 seems ok to backtrack.

Comment: @algrid nope i haven't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Java Code for Algrid's answer :

```
public class Main {

static double min_d = 1e+10;

// diagonal distance factor cos(45), needs to multiply with hypotenuse 
static double c = 0.707110678; 

static double xt = 7.0;
static double yt = 17.0;

public static void solve(int time, double x, double y, double dirX, double dirY) {

    double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - xt), 2) + Math.pow((y - yt), 2));
    if( d < min_d )
        min_d = d;

    if( time == 0 || (d-time * 10) >= min_d ){
        return;
    }

    solve(time - 1, x + dirX, y + dirY, dirX, dirY);
    solve(time - 1, x, y, c * (dirX - dirY), c * (dirX + dirY));
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    solve(9, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
}

}// Class END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create a graph for every possible stop of the robot and its orientation. Which will be a triple (x, y, orientation) and orientation is one of 0,1,..,7. For each orientation i moving forward is given by the vector orientation_vec[i]

```
import networkx as nx


def one_second(G):
    # In each step you can either go forward or turn. Create one edge
    # for each node and these two possible moves.
    orientation_vec = [(10000000, 0), (7071067, -7071067), (0, -10000000),
                       (-7071067, -7071067), (-10000000, 0), (-7071067, 7071067),
                       (0, 10000000), (7071067, 7071067)]

    for node in G.nodes():
        # edge to next orientation
        G.add_edge(node, (node[0], node[1], (node[2] + 1)%8))
        # edge going forward
        G.add_edge(node, (node[0] + orientation_vec[node[2]][0],
                          node[1] + orientation_vec[node[2]][1],
                          node[2]))


def create_graph(max_time):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_node(n=(0, 0, 0))
    for t in range(max_time):
       one_second(G)
    print(len(G.nodes()))
```

We can now go through all nodes and find the closest to the target.
Once the graph is created we can find the shortest path by using dijkstra or A*. I used the networkx package for that.

```
import math

def find_closest_path(paths, end):
    min_dist = end[0]**2 + end[1]**2
    best_path = None
    for key in paths.keys():
        end_path = paths[key][-1]
        path_to_end = (end_path[0] - end[0])**2 + (end_path[1]-end[1])**2
        if path_to_end < min_dist:
            min_dist = path_to_end
            best_path = paths[key]
    min_dist = math.sqrt(min_dist)/10**6
    x = [p[0]/10**6 for p in best_path]
    y = [p[1]/10**6 for p in best_path]
    return min_dist, x, y 


def robot_path(end, max_time):
    create_graph(max_time)
    paths = nx.single_source_shortest_path(G, (0, 0, 0), cutoff=max_time)
    return find_closest_path(paths, end)
```

A plotting function i copy pasted from stackoverflow somewhere.

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_robot_path(x,y, end):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    color=['b']*len(x) + ['r']

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    scatter(x+[end[0]], y+[end[1]], s=100 ,marker='o', c=color)

    [plot([x[i], x[i+1]], [y[i], y[i+1]], '-', linewidth=3 ) for i in range(len(x)-1)] 

    left,right = ax.get_xlim()
    low,high = ax.get_ylim()
    arrow(left, 0, right -left, 0, length_includes_head = True, head_width = 0.15 )
    arrow(0, low, 0, high-low, length_includes_head = True, head_width = 0.15 ) 

    grid()

    show()
```

If we run it i get the following results:

```
end1=(5*10**6, 5*10**6)
max_time = 24
min_dist1, x1, y1 = robot_path(end1, max_time)
print(min_dist1)
plot_robot_path(x1, y1, (5, 5))

max_time=9
end2=(7*10**6, 17*10**6)
min_dist2, x2, y2 = robot_path(end2, max_time)
print(min_dist2)
plot_robot_path(x2, y2, (7, 17))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's compact backtracking solution:

```
import math

min_d = 1e+10
c = 0.70710678
xt = 5.0
yt = 5.0

def solve(remaining_t, x, y, dir_x, dir_y):
    global min_d
    d = math.sqrt((x - xt)**2 + (y - yt)**2)
    if d < min_d:
        min_d = d
    if remaining_t == 0 or d - remaining_t * 10 >= min_d:
        return 
    solve(remaining_t - 1, x + dir_x, y + dir_y, dir_x, dir_y)
    solve(remaining_t - 1, x, y, c * (dir_x - dir_y), c * (dir_x + dir_y))

solve(24, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0)
print(min_d)
```

It takes ~5 sec. on my computer.

A bit of explanation:

`min_d` - is the current minimum distance, we initialized it with a large value (should be greater than any distance could possibly be)

The `solve` function takes the following parameters:

`remaining_t` - remaining time in seconds, on each step it's decreased by 1

`x` and `y` - current coordinates of the bot

`dir_x`, `dir_y` - coordinates of bot's current direction vector. This vector has length 10 an we start with this vector pointing towards the `x` axis: (10, 0)

At each step the `solve` function considers current distance to the target point and updates `min_d` if needed. If there's no remaining time left or we have gone too far from the target point we stop going forward immediately. Otherwise we try 1) go forward 2) turn 45 degrees.

1. When bot is going forward (considering current direction) `x` becomes `x+dir_x` and `y` becomes `y+dir_y`. The direction vector stays the same.
2. When the bot turns, its coordinates stay the same but the direction vector changes. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix (our constant c = sin 45 = cos 45)

Comment: Thanks it worked but I'm facing problems understanding the code, kindly could you briefly explain the code. Just the part inside the function `solve` and why `min_d = 1e+10`?

Comment: @MirwiseKhan I added more explanations to the answer